# Capistrano all of sudden stopped working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I am deploying the Rails 4.1 code using capistron 2.

Everything was working fine I did some changes in schedule.rb file for whenever i.e.

```
set :output, {:error => 'error.log', :standard => 'cron.log'}
```

to

```
set :output, {:error => 'log/error.log', :standard => 'log/cron.log'}
```

and deployed code and it worked fine for first time.

Now when I deployed again, I firstly faced error during deployment.

```
bundler: command not found: whenever
```

I installed whenever gem separately on production:-

```
gem install whenever -v 0.9.4
```

Now on deploy again, its still broken and error is:-

```
Executing "cp -- /home/myusername/project/production/shared/assets/manifest-74e7866cd14bb57f565f7e816b8116fd.json /home/myusername/project/production/releases/database.yml/assets_manifest.json

failed to access ‘/home/myusername/project/production/releases/database.yml/assets_manifest.json

[whenever:update_crontab] rolling back
```

The one thing I am confused about is why it is moving the manifest file to releases/database.yml/assets_manifest.json directory but it should be the release number.